# Need to find a power adapter

Tags: cpu, power, fan, adapter

Just finished upgrading the heatsink and fan in my wife's computer (dropped the temperature about 20 degrees on an AMD), and everything works great except one problem.  The BIOS is reporting that it can't find the CPU fan, which it can't because the stock fan had a 4 pin connector and the new one only has a 3 pin.  I'd like to find, if possible, some sort of adapter (note: not looking for an adapter to a [4 pin drive connector](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812200499&cm_re=fan_adapter-_-12-200-499-_-Product)) that will let me plug the fan into the correct slot so the computer doesn't complain every boot.  So far, I haven't been able tofind anything searching myself.  Does anyone know where I can find such a beast?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is [this](http://www.endpcnoise.com/cgi-bin/e/std/sku=4pin_3pin_fan_adapter.html) what you're looking for? [Here](http://www.frozencpu.com/products/8881/cab-169/4-pin_PWM_Male_to_3-pin_Female_Adapter_Cable_12_-_Sleeved_Black_CB-PWM-3F.html?tl=g47c251) is another choice.

Comment: The second choice led me to another adapter on that site which provides exactly what I need (http://www.frozencpu.com/products/9081/bus-190/Nanoxia_PWMX_3_to_4_Pin_PWM_Controller.html?tl=g47c251).  Thanks